# How to attach one sprite to another in LibGDX?

Tags: 2d, sprites, libgdx

I want to attach one sprite to another so that it is always located at the 'bottom' of the other sprite, regardless of how the main sprite is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the attached sprite be an entirely separate entity, and just have this entity be moved beneath the original entity each time this entity updates.  If you were using scene2d actors, you could have the bottom sprite just be an actor that continuously executes the MoveToAction with a duration of 0, instantly moving beneath the upper sprite (actor).